# Подключение библиотек (модулей) js в Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular2, typescript, npm

Хотел бы получить текст Word документа (.docx). Нашел решение на [github](https://github.com/kmaher9/docx_parser)

Как добавить данное решение в проект и использовать это в своих компонентах? Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Это серверное решение. Вам нужно загружать документ на сервер и там его парсить.

Comment: @sneas Не могли бы вы подсказать с чего начать?